Can't see a room that was created by a player who already was in a room and then left in Unity 3D + Photon Pun
I have a public room list.
    public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
    {
        foreach (RoomInfo room in roomList)
        {
            if (room.RemovedFromList)
            {
                cachedRoomList.Remove(room);
            }
            else
            {
                int index = cachedRoomList.FindIndex(r => r.Name == room.Name);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    cachedRoomList[index] = room;
                }
                else
                {
                    cachedRoomList.Add(room);
                }
            }
        }
        UpdatePublicRoomUI();
    }

    void UpdatePublicRoomUI()
    {
        foreach (Transform roomButton in publicRoomContainer)
        {
            Destroy(roomButton.gameObject);
        }

        foreach (RoomInfo room in cachedRoomList)
        {
            CreatePublicRoomButton(room.Name, room.PlayerCount);
        }
    }

    void CreatePublicRoomButton(string roomName, int playerCount)
    {
        GameObject roomButton = Instantiate(publicRoomButton, publicRoomContainer);
        roomButton.SetActive(true);

        roomButton.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().SetText(roomName);
        roomButton.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().SetText(playerCount.ToString());

        UnityEngine.UI.Button button = roomButton.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();
        button.onClick.AddListener(() =>
        {
            JoinRoom(roomName);
        });
    }

So basically, every room that has the option IsVisible set to true will show up here.
Everything works fine until the player leaves a room and then creates one. No matter if it is public or not, it won't show up here. Here's the room leaving code:
    public void QuitToMenu()
    {
        if (PhotonNetwork.InRoom)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
            PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Menu");
        }
    }

Here are the room creating and joining functions:
    public void CreateRoom(string roomName, bool isPublic)
    {
        RoomOptions roomOptions = new()
        {
            IsVisible = isPublic,
            IsOpen = true,
            MaxPlayers = 10
        };
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName, roomOptions);
    }

    public void JoinRoom(string roomName)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(roomName);
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        string nickname = nickname_input.text.Trim();
        if (nickname.Length > 0)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetString("Nickname", nickname);
            PhotonNetwork.NickName = nickname;
        }
        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("Game");
    }

It will be cool to see it working properly. Thanks in advance.
